# Ruby - Continuously reading from the end of a file

Tags: ruby

I have made a Ruby program that should read the end of a **Linux** log file, as well any additional information that is added to the end of the file during the execution of the script. A regular expression is then used to match specific lines, such as can be seen below.

> Mar 31 13:28:05 dns.ns1.local dnsmasq[82093]: query[A] ns1.localdomain
>   from 192.168.10.2

The program should then mail the whole line to a local user (which can be done manually), doing so indefinitely, while applying the same procedure to any additional information that is added to the log file. The idea is that the program should never exit.

I can run my program without any errors, using **ruby name_of_program.rb /var/log/messages**, providing tsystemhe path to the log file as an argument. The issue lies in the fact that the program does not fulfill any of the tasks that can otherwise be carried out manually.

My Ruby program:

```
open(ARGV.first) do |file|
    file.seek(0, IO::SEEK_END)
    loop do
        changes = file.read
        unless changes.empty?
            if changes =~ /query.*ns1.localdomain/
                cmd "echo Q%DNS_QUERY_TO_WWW -> #{file}Q% | /usr/sbin/sendmail berit"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Any input as to what I'm missing would be appreciated.

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/ruby/chkbuild/blob/master/tail-f

Answer (score 0):

The issue seemed to stem from the system output, which I solved with the following fix.

```
open(ARGV.first) do |file|
    file.seek(0, IO::SEEK_END)
    loop do
        changes = file.read
        unless changes.empty?
            if changes =~ /query.*ns1.localdomain/
                system "echo '#{changes}' | /usr/sbin/sendmail berit\n"
            end
        end
    end
end
```